# WPF app with Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, ninject

I'm lost with Ninject in WPF.

I'm initializing it in App.xaml but the ITest property in MainWindow.xaml (even with the InjectAttribute) is not getting resolved and remains null.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {    
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ITest, Test>();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

I googled a bit and found out that it doesn't work that way. In trying to find a solution, I ended up with creating IMainWindow with nothing else but "void Show();" and adding it to the MainWindow.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {    
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ITest, Test>();

        kernel.Bind<IMainWindow, MySolution.MainWindow>();
        kernel.Get<IMainWindow>().Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

For this, I'm getting a NullReferenceException on the line with .Get

I also tried this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {    
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ITest, Test>();

        MainWindow = new MySolution.MainWindow(kernel);
        //then kernel.Inject(this); in the MainWindow constructor 
        MainWindow.Show();

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

Now I'm getting a NullReferenceException at the .Inject line in the MainWindow.

I found another various solutions but they seemed heavyweight and I gave up testing all of them and trying which one works.

Any help please?

Comment: What exactly is your `NullReferenceException` is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not registering your types correctly that is why the second example throws an execption. The correct syntax is: `kernel.Bind<SomeInterface>().To<SomeImplementation>()`

So the correct usage:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();

    kernel.Bind<IMainWindow>().To<MainWindow>();
    var mainWindow = kernel.Get<IMainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

And you need to mark your property with the `[Inject]` attribute:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Inject]
    public ITest Test { get; set; }
}

public interface IMainWindow
{
    void Show();
}
```

Comment: Huh, I thought Bind<T1, T2>() is the same as Bind<T1>().To<T2>(). Evidently not. Thanks!

Comment: No with `Bind<T1, T2>()` you can bind two interfaces to one implementation but you still need to provide the implementation with `.To<>`.

Comment: I know this is old but when I do this, I get two Main Windows showing, as opposed to one. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JMK Have you removed the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from your app.xaml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you got a solution, but you can use constructor injection instead of property injection on MainWindow, if you want.

This avoids creating a Dummy interface IMainWindow and creating a unnecessary public property for all your injected classes.

Here's the solution:

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IMainWindow
{
    private readonly ITest test;

    public MainWindow(ITest test)
    {
        this.test = test;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
    kernel.Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();

    var mainWindow = kernel.Get<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.Show();

    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```